# Java Void to Scala Unit

Tags: java, scala, void, scalac, scala-compiler

I have a java library method requiring a class of `Void` as a parameter. for example, in `com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollection`:

```
void insertOne(TDocument document, SingleResultCallback<Void> callback);
```

I'm accessing this method from scala. Scala uses the type `Unit` as equivalent of `Void` (correct me if I'm wrong please)

How can I pass a `SingleResultCallback[Unit]` (instead of `SingleResultCallback[Void]`) to this method? The compiler is not allowing this. Shouldn't it be picking this up?

Comment: Give it a function which the last line is equals to ``()`` no ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scala's `Unit` is like Java's `void` primitive, but it's not exactly the same thing.

Scala's `Unit` type and Java's `Void` type are completely unrelated. Java's `Void` class exists so you can use it as a type parameter analogous to primitive `void`, just like `Integer` exists as an analogue to primitive `int`. In Scala, `Unit` fulfills the role of both `Void` and `void`.

An implicit conversion between `Unit` and `Void` cannot exist, because implicit conversions work on instances, not on types. Also, Java's `Void` type cannot have an instance. (Scala's `Unit` does have an instance: `()`.)

Long story short, Scala's `Unit` and Java's `Void` are different beasts. Since your Java library requires the `Void` type parameter, you should just give it that.

Answer (score 4):

Java's `Void` is from my experience usually used with `null` as its only value, where as `Unit` also only has one value: `()`.
SingleResultCallback is just a SAM type of `(T, Throwable) => Unit`. This means we can convert these from and to `Unit` if we want:

```
def toUnit(cb: SingleResultCallback[Void]): SingleResultCallback[Unit] =
  (u, throwable) => cb(null, throwable)

def fromUnit(cb: SingleResultCallback[Unit]): SingleResultCallback[Void] =
  (v, throwable) => cb((), throwable)
```

This is assuming you use Scala 2.12.*. Otherwise you will need to construct an Instance of `SingleResultCallback` using `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [javatoscala](http://javatoscala.com/)

It returned:

```
def insertOne(document: TDocument,
                callback: SingleResultCallback[Void]): Unit
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer my question. I want to pass callback = `SingleResultCallback[Unit]`, not `SingleResultCallback[Void]` to this method. How do I do that? There is no implicit conversion from `Void` to `Unit`.